# ¿Como puedo insertar en la B.D la fecha actual desde codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Tengo un problema, al insertar la fecha actual desde codeigniter a la B.D no puedo, me dice que no se puede insertar un array básicamente. ¿Como lo puedo insertar? Agradezco sus respuestas.
Estoy tratando de insertar la fecha_de_alta.

Este es mi modelo

```
function guardaRecepcion($medicamento_id,$medicamento_desc,$fecha_de_entrada,$fecha_de_alta,$entrante,$fecha_caducidad,$lote,$orden_compra)
  {
    $query="INSERT INTO `ctrl_stock_entrante`(`medicamento_id`,`medicamento_desc`,`fecha_de_entrada`,`fecha_de_alta`,`entrante`,`fecha_caducidad`,`lote`,`orden_compra`)
    VALUES ('$medicamento_id','$medicamento_desc','$fecha_de_entrada','$fecha_de_alta','$entrante','$fecha_caducidad','$lote','$orden_compra')";
    $this->db->query($query);
  }
```

Este es mi controlador

```
public function altaRecepcion(){

  if($this->input->post('type')==1)
  {
    $medicamento_id=$this->input->post('medicamento_id');
    $medicamento_desc=$this->input->post('medicamento_desc');
    $fecha_de_entrada=$this->input->post('fecha_de_entrada');
    $entrante=$this->input->post('entrante');
    $fecha_caducidad=$this->input->post('fecha_caducidad');
    $lote=$this->input->post('lote');
    $orden_compra=$this->input->post('orden_compra');
    date_default_timezone_set('America/mexico_city'); # add your city to set local time zone
   $fecha_de_alta['fecha_de_alta'] = date('Y-m-d H:m:s');

    $this->Inventario_model->guardaRecepcion($medicamento_id,$medicamento_desc,$fecha_de_entrada,$fecha_de_alta,$entrante,$fecha_caducidad,$lote,$orden_compra);
    echo json_encode(array(
      "statusCode"=>200
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Estás creando el parámetro como una clave de array aquí: `$fecha_de_alta['fecha_de_alta'] = date('Y-m-d H:m:s');` cámbialo simplemente por esto: `$fecha_de_alta = date('Y-m-d H:m:s');` y considera escribir consultas preparadas, tu código es susceptible de Inyección SQL.

Comment: Hola: `$fecha_de_alta['fecha_de_alta'] = date('Y-m-d H:m:s');` es un array, de la forma ['fecha_de_alta' => date('Y-m-d H:m:s'), ] y debiera ser algo del estilo de `$fecha_de_alta = pasarAlFormatoDeterminadoParaTuFecha( date('Y-m-d H:m:s') );`

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por su respuesta, si me sirvió de las dos formas. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás creando el parámetro como array aquí:

```
$fecha_de_alta['fecha_de_alta'] = date('Y-m-d H:m:s');
```

Debes cambiarlo por esto:

```
$fecha_de_alta = date('Y-m-d H:m:s');
```

En cuanto a tu consulta, deberías escribir una consulta preparada para dar seguridad al código:

```
function guardaRecepcion($medicamento_id,$medicamento_desc,$fecha_de_entrada,$fecha_de_alta,$entrante,$fecha_caducidad,$lote,$orden_compra)
{
    $query="INSERT INTO `ctrl_stock_entrante`(`medicamento_id`,`medicamento_desc`,`fecha_de_entrada`,`fecha_de_alta`,`entrante`,`fecha_caducidad`,`lote`,`orden_compra`)
    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    $mParams=array($medicamento_id, $medicamento_desc, $fecha_de_entrada, $fecha_de_alta, $entrante,$fecha_caducidad, $lote, $orden_compra);
    $this->db->query($query,$mParams);
}
```

Considera usar nombres de variables menos laaaaargos. Produce un código ilegible.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta la probé y me dio el resultado que quería. Gracias y si evitaré poner esos nombres. Gracias.